# Relative Referencing in Visual Studio 2013 (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, dll

**Problem:** So, my issue is that I have 3 .dll files I want to include in my software. However, whenever I transfer the .exe to another computer, it looks for my hard coded absolute path in my computer. I want the dlls to be included or embedded such that I can distribute it to others.

**Setup:**

I have done so by going to the solution explorer and doing Add->Exisiting Item, and add the three dlls into the solution explorer.

Then I went to each .dll's properties and changed them so that they are considered embedded resources. Like so:

[image: Woo for visuals]

Then I went to the references tab of the project property, and added a reference to the three dlls in my code. I originally had them in my /bin/ folder of my project, but I still had this problem. so I added them here in the same folder as my project.

[image]

Great, so I compile, copy to another computer, and get an exception (I threw it to a message box for ease) saying it can't find the dll and/or its dependencies. I even put a copy of the dll in the same .exe folder on the separate computer, but the same problem.

**What I've Tried:** So I tried messing around with the project file. But it looked ok to me. Here's a snippet:

```
 <ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="PcapDotNet.Base, Version=0.10.0.20588, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b6f3e583145a652, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>.\PcapDotNet.Base.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="PcapDotNet.Core, Version=0.10.0.20632, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b6f3e583145a652, processorArchitecture=x86">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>.\PcapDotNet.Core.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="PcapDotNet.Packets, Version=0.10.0.20603, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b6f3e583145a652, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>.\PcapDotNet.Packets.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System" />
<Reference Include="System.Data" />
<Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
<Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml" />
<Reference Include="System.Core" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
```

and later ...

```
 <ItemGroup>
<EmbeddedResource Include="PcapDotNet.Base.dll" />
<EmbeddedResource Include="PcapDotNet.Core.dll" />
<EmbeddedResource Include="PcapDotNet.Packets.dll" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

**Question:** So, why is it saying it can't find the dll? Where could it still be looking for it in the wrong place?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: "Embedded resource" just doesn't mean what you think it does.  It puts a copy of the DLL inside the EXE.  Where nobody can find it back anymore, least of all Windows.  Instead set the Copy to Output Directory to "Copy if newer".  If you want a single deployable file then use an installer builder utility to create "setup.exe".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys! I found the solution was a problem with Pcap dot net (pcap.net). The issue was that the supporting computer didn't have the Microsoft Redistributable C++ package. It says that is needed on their website. I thought that was for development only, but turns out it is needed for running as well. I might try to include those dll's in the embedded resources as well to clean it up for the user.